# Update database when user is no more online

Tags: php, mysql, online-game

I am currently working on a Javascript multiplayer game.

When users want to play, they enter a waiting room where they wait for players to play with.

It is stored in a SQL database this way :
I have a table named `USER` with some data on the players, and another table named `WAITINGROOM` which associates the id `USERID` of the user waiting for a game with other infos.

When players leave the waiting room or close their browser, I delete the row with their id in table `WAITINGROOM`.

But let's suppose the user loses his internet connection while looking for a game. How can I know he is offline so I can remove the row containing his id ?

The player is offline so it is definitely not client side I can deal with this.
Maybe server side in PHP ? Or directly in the database using timeouts or something...

Comment: I think you can use a function to check if users in waitingroom are online or not. then run that function with cron-job for example every 1 minute.

Comment: The function to check if users are online or not is my problem, because I can't send or receive data from them.

Comment: Look at this, I think it could be helpful
 https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/254730/how-could-i-detect-users-that-are-offline-and-online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a script (probably called via ajax) which fetches the online users for the current user. Simply add a column like 'last_seen_online' with a timestamp. Update the field every time the user calls this script. Now you can filter it in your sql for example get all users which have been online during the last minute. - Everything not active since one minute is considered offline like this.

To get rid of users which went offline you can implement a garbage collection(like php with sessions does). You grab all users which havent been seen since the last (for example)5 minutes. You place this garbage collection in the same script. To keep the load low. You dont call it every time, just like 50% of the time with `if(rand(1,100) > 50)` or any percentage you like.

Comment: I indeed use ajax to fetch onlines players. I will use your solution. I'm wondering what's the best way to get rid of offline users in my SQL table... I could use your solution in JS but maybe I could also do it in SQL with triggers on update ?

Comment: Garbage collect then use SQL something like this: `DELETE FROM users WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-300) > YOUR_LAST_ONLINE_TIMESTAMP ` 300 for 5 minues (60*5)